# How to change the group id of a file on rooted android device?

Tags: android, root

I am trying to give access to a file I have written in one app to another app.
`chgrp` is not available in the adb shell (`command 'chgrp' not found`)
I have installed BusyBox but in order to get access to `chgrp`.

For example I use the command `chown app_79 file.txt` and it works. 
But when I try `chgrp app_79 file.txt` it always returns something like `chgrp: unknown group app_79`

I Googled a bunch and found that most linux systems have a file `/etc/group` which stores the group information for that system, but it is not present in Android.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using the builtin tools, rather than busybox, it would be

```
chown uid.gid filename
```

Probably with these id's having to be numeric as Matt pointed out.

Comment: The ids did NOT have to be numeric for me. `root.root` and `root.system` worked for instance on my device.

Comment: Note that in Linux `chown owner:group filepath` generally works vs this period syntax.

Answer (score 7):

Use `busybox chown uid.gid file.txt` and specify UID and GID as numbers instead of names. `app_79` likely [corresponds](http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h) to ID 10079 (to be sure you may recheck it with `busybox ls -l -n /data/data`):

```
busybox chown 10079.10079 file.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Found some information [here](https://github.com/keesj/gomo/wiki/AndroidSecurityUserAndGroups) about how some group ids are hardcoded. I also had previous knowledge that `/data/system/packages.list` and `/data/system/packages.xml` contained the UIDs of apps, which are all something like 10000+x. What I now know is that x is the number that comes after "app_" when you ls -l.

So, the weird thing is you can `chgrp 10079 file.txt` but you cannot `chgrp app_79 file.txt`.

Hope this helps someone.